# Symfony 4 Translations not displaying

Tags: php, symfony, translation

So I have the following demo for the **Symfony 4** framework which works fine and translates everything as expected:

```
$translator = new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator('en_GB');
$translator->addLoader('array', new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\ArrayLoader());
$translator->addResource('array', [
    'sample' => 'The English translation goes here...',
], 'en_GB');
echo $translator->trans('sample');
```

However I can't seem to get the following demo to work:

```
echo $this->get('translator')->trans('sample');
```

The following config is in place:

/config/services.yaml:

```
parameters:
    locale: en
```

/config/packages/translation.yaml:

```
framework:
    default_locale: en
    translator:
        fallbacks: ['en']
        paths:
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
```

/translations/messages.en.yaml:

```
sample: The English translation goes here...
```

Dumping out the following:

```
$request->getLocale();
$request->getDefaultLocale();
```

Produces the following strings:

```
'en_GB'
'en'
```

And I've tried renaming the translation file to 'messages.**en**.yaml', 'messages.**en_GB**.yaml', 'messages.**en_US**.yaml' and then run "**php bin/console cache:clear**" afterwards to ensure the cache was fully cleared.

I can't seem to get the translations to display from the yaml file. There are no errors displaying but only the translation keys are visible.

Can anyone see if I'm making an obvious mistake somewhere or overlooking something?

PHP 7.2.0-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2 (cli) (built: Dec 7 2017 20:14:31) ( NTS ) Linux Mint 18, Apache2 Ubuntu.

Comment: What is full path of `messages.en.yaml`?

Comment: @drkey The full path is specified in the question already. It's '/translations/messages.en.yaml', /translations is in the same directory as 'src' and 'public'.

Comment: Then what you get by executing `php bin/console debug:container --parameter=kernel.project_dir`?

Comment: kernel.project_dir:   /var/www/html/projects/symfony4Test

Comment: did you found a solution? i am struggling with the same problem at the moment.

Comment: You might want to do a ```php bin/console debug:translation <lang>```. I had this problem using xliff for the first time (as opposed to yaml). I realized that my translations wasn't done properly. ``` ----------- ---------- ---------------- ---------------------- 
  State       Domain     Id               Message Preview (fr)  
 ----------- ---------- ---------------- ---------------------- 
   missing    messages   home             home                  
   unused     messages   Home             Accueil   ```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and i found a solution . Maybe this is a solution for someone else too.
In my case the command

```
./bin/console cache:clear
```

didn't cleared the /var/cache/translations folder. After dropping this folder manually

```
rm -rf var/log/translations
```

the translations were loaded like expected.

I don't know why the cache:clear isn't working probably in this case, but at the moment i get along with it. Maybe i find some time next week to debug the reason.

Comment: Mine started working with first rm -rf var/log/translations and then ./bin/console cache:clear